# how can I fix the error with making mtree

Tags: iphone, terminal, makefile, configure

Hello I'm new to this and I don't understand, what's going on.
I need [mtree](http://code.google.com/p/mtree-port/) for my iPhone and got an error.
And this is what I get:

```
In file included from compare.c:62:
vis.h:43: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘size_t’
In file included from compare.c:65:
extern.h:52: warning: redundant redeclaration of ‘compare’
extern.h:40: warning: previous declaration of ‘compare’ was here
extern.h:59: warning: redundant redeclaration of ‘getmode’
/usr/include/unistd.h:700: warning: previous declaration of ‘getmode’ was here
extern.h:60: warning: redundant redeclaration of ‘setmode’
/usr/include/unistd.h:736: warning: previous declaration of ‘setmode’ was here
compare.c: In function ‘compare’:
compare.c:186: error: ‘struct stat’ has no member named ‘st_mtim’
compare.c:187: error: ‘struct stat’ has no member named ‘st_mtim’
compare.c:192: error: ‘struct stat’ has no member named ‘st_mtim’
make[1]: *** [compare.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The full message is at http://pastebin.com/rVUfVP75

Answer (score 0):

```
compare.c:186: error: ‘struct stat’ has no member named ‘st_mtim’
```

It should be st_mtime.  It looks like a typo.

The structure definition is here:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html

Comment: I don't know what to do. Can somebody help me please?